# How to emulate bash select command in batch DOS?

Tags: batch-file

Hi i have a variable containig a list of folders separated by a space, i want to present these elements each precedeed by a number, the user choses a folder by entreing the number associated with it, once that done, i want to get the element associated with the number and cd to it. In linux you can do that by select command but it batch, there's no such command, choice command isn't really helpful in my case i think.

For diplaying it's fine, here'S my code:

```
@echo off
set folderlist=C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\TecsysCP C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\mast_main_dtw1i C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\dev_main_dtw1o

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set Count=1

echo.
echo Please choose a folder:
echo.
for %%z in (%folderlist%) do (
  echo !Count!^) %%z
  Set /A Count+=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

CHOICE can work fine as long as you are not on XP, and the maximum number of choices is limited.

If the list size is always less then 10, then you can dynamically build the list of CHOICE keys. (Note that I put ECHO before the CD so I could test):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderlist=C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\TecsysCP C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\mast_main_dtw1i C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\dev_main_dtw1o

set count=1
set "choice="
echo(
echo Please choose a folder:
echo(
for %%F in (%folderlist%) do (
  echo !count!^) %%~F
  set "choice=!choice!!count!"
  set "option.!count!=%%F"
  set /a count+=1
)
echo(
choice /c %choice% /m ">" /n
echo cd !option.%errorlevel%!
```

If the list size can exceed 9, then you can predefine a list of choices and use a substring with the count to limit them appropriately:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderlist=C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\TecsysCP C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\mast_main_dtw1i C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\dev_main_dtw1o C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12

set count=0
set "choice=123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
echo(
echo Please choose a folder:
echo(
for %%F in (%folderlist%) do (
  for %%N in (!count!) do echo !choice:~%%N,1!^) %%~F
  set /a count+=1
  set "option.!count!=%%F"
)
echo(
choice /c !choice:~0,%count%! /m ">" /n
echo cd !option.%errorlevel%!
```

If you must support XP, or if you want an unconstrained list, then you can switch to using SET /P. I included code to verify the user's input, and loop back if the value is not valid.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderlist=C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\TecsysCP C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\mast_main_dtw1i C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\dev_main_dtw1o C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12

:menu
set count=1
set "valid= "
echo(
echo Please choose a folder:
echo(
for %%F in (%folderlist%) do (
  echo !count!^) %%~F
  set "valid=!valid!!count! "
  set "option.!count!=%%F"
  set /a count+=1
)
echo(
set "choice=0"
set /p "choice=> "
if "!valid: %choice% =!" equ "!valid!" (
  echo Invalid choice, please try again.
  pause
  goto menu
)
echo cd !option.%choice%!
```